# passport-oauth accessing remote url

Tags: node.js, oauth, passport.js

I try to implement an OAuth solution in nodejs. I used passport-oauth for generating the acccess tokens and refresh tokens which is working.

```
var passport = require('passport'),
    OAuth = require('oauth').OAuth,
    url = require('url'),
    ArenaNet = require('passport-oauth').OAuth2Strategy,
    config = require('../config'),
    users = require('../../app/controllers/users.server.controller');

 module.exports = function() {
    passport.use('arenanet', new ArenaNet({
        authorizationURL: config.arenanet.authorizationURL,
        tokenURL: config.arenanet.tokenURL,
        clientID: config.arenanet.clientID,
        clientSecret: config.arenanet.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: config.arenanet.callbackURL,
        response_type: "code",
        scope: "offline account"
      },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, code, profile, done) {
        console.log(accessToken);
        console.log(refreshToken);
        console.log(code);

        done();
    }));
};
```

This generates the following output:

```
69XXXXF-776D-4CXX-AXX7-29XXXXXX4DB5
5FXXXXXX-XXX67-E1XXX1-809D-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XX69-4XX6-XXF-4C6XXXXX08EB
{ access_token: 'XX0XXXXXF-77XXX-4XXXX-XXXA7-295XXXXXXB5',
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  scope: 'account' }
```

I am new to OAuth. What confuses me now is how to access a remote url with the tokens. What i have in mind is something like this:

```
oauth.get(
            "https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/account",
            accessToken,
            function(err, body, response) {
                console.log(body);
            }
        );
```

What obviously don't work. I saw several examples how i can access local sites with the token, but not how to request something from a remote url.

Any suggestion how i'm able to this with passport-oauth? Or do i need to use a different module for this action?

I hope you can help me here, would be cool!

Thank you all and best regards,
michael

Comment: Any luck with this question?  I'm having the same issue at the moment!